# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attname'

Tags: python, django

I am using this [django_multitenant](https://github.com/citusdata/django-multitenant/tree/main/django_multitenant) library to implement multi tenancy. I tried creating an object in python manage.py shell using the below code

```
>>> from ReportingWebapp.models import *
>>> from django_multitenant.utils import *
>>> org = Organization.objects.first()
>>> set_current_tenant(org)
>>> get_current_tenant()
<Organization: Organization object (1)>
>>> a = ApplicationSetting(username="a",password="b",client_secret="c",client_id="d",tenant_id="e")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\reporting_multitenant\env\lib\site-packages\django_multitenant\mixins.py", line 58, in __init__
    super(TenantModelMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\reporting_multitenant\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 416, in __init__
    self._state = ModelState()
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\reporting_multitenant\env\lib\site-packages\django_multitenant\mixins.py", line 62, in __setattr__
    if (attrname in (self.tenant_field, get_tenant_field(self).name)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\reporting_multitenant\env\lib\site-packages\django_multitenant\mixins.py", line 115, in tenant_field
    return self.tenant_id
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\reporting_multitenant\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query_utils.py", line 149, in __get__
    instance.refresh_from_db(fields=[field_name])
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\reporting_multitenant\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 623, in refresh_from_db
    db_instance_qs = self.__class__._base_manager.db_manager(using, hints=hints).filter(pk=self.pk)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\reporting_multitenant\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 573, in _get_pk_val
    return getattr(self, meta.pk.attname)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\reporting_multitenant\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query_utils.py", line 147, in __get__
    val = self._check_parent_chain(instance)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\reporting_multitenant\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query_utils.py", line 163, in _check_parent_chain
    return getattr(instance, link_field.attname)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attname'
```

Why did i get this error? Tenant is already set in thread local.

models.py

```
class Organization(TenantModel):
    tenant_id = 'id'
    org_name = models.CharField('Organization Name',max_length=200)
    num_agents = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        'Number of agents',
        help_text = 'Approximate number of agents who possess microsoft teams license'
        )
    admin_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    admin_email = models.EmailField()


class ApplicationSetting(TenantModel):
    org = models.ForeignKey(Organization,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tenant_id='organization_id'
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    client_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    client_secret = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tenant_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    user_token = models.TextField(null=True)
    app_token = models.TextField(null=True)
```

Comment: Please show your models

Comment: @LordElrond Added. Thanks !

Comment: Who so ever will be reading this question in future. Issue in ```ApplicationSetting``` model was, i was already using ```tenant_id``` as a field name for azure active directory application id. Then i used the same field name to link this model for django multitenancy. This caused the issue. Next issue was, i was using ```org = models.ForeignKey(Organization,on_delete=models.CASCADE)``` in ```Application Setting```. Ideally it should be ```organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization,on_delete=models.CASCADE)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is due to the `tenant_id` *model field* you declared in your
`ApplicationSetting` model.  Internally, the package you are using appears to use `tenant_id` as a reference to the field name of the tenant-related foreign key.

Since you declared `tenant_id` as a nullable field, the original `tenant_id='organization_id'` no longer exists.  When you initialize your `ApplicationSetting`, the **`TenantManager`** looks for a field named **`None`** and tries to find it's *related name* (via the `attname` property), hence the error.

To fix this, remove the **`tenant_id`** field.

After, you will probably get different exception, because your `ApplicationSetting` model doesn't contain a field named **`organization`**.  To fix this, you will need to rename your **`org`** field:

```
organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization,on_delete=models.CASCADE)'
```

Alternatively, you can change the `tenant_id` to **`org_id`** instead.

**Disclaimer:** I'm not at all familiar with the package you are using.

Comment: Changes i made:   ```class ApplicationSetting(TenantModel):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tenant_id='organization_id'``` .  Then i did ```python manage.py makemigrations``` and ```python manage.py migrate```. Again i am getting the same error.

Comment: @AmandeepSinghSawhney did you remove the `tenant_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)` ?

Comment: I have not defined tenant_id like this. I copy pasted exact code in question. Added new changes in the question. Thanks for devoting your time to help me out.

Comment: @AmandeepSinghSawhney check your `ApplicationSetting` model.  The code you posted has a model field called **`tenant_id`**.

Comment: Sorry i got it. One tenant_id is AzureActiveDirectory tenant id and other is django_multitenant tenant_id. Stupid me. I forgot that i am already using the same name. Let me make some changes and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Thanks ! I wish i could upvote this 100 times.